# Minor JavaScript array error

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var add = [];

add[0].url = data.url;
add[0].photo = data.thumb;

console.log(add);
```

This'll be an instant know for most JS people. The code above is failing, anyone able to tell me where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`add[0]` doesn't exist... `.push` something first.

```
add.push({ url:data.url, photo:data.thumb })
```

or

```
add[0] = {};
add[0].url = 'blah';
add[0].photo = 'foo'
```

Answer (score 4):

You are assigning to properties of the `add[0]` object but you haven't made any such object.

```
add[0] = { };
add[0].url = data.url;
add[0].photo = data.thumb;
```

Answer (score 3):

A different option for you; instead of pushing into an empty array, and declaring an empty object

```
var add = new Array(); //create new array object
add[0] = {url:data.url, photo:data.thumb}; //add new object with items url and photo
```